# Implementing recaptcha in Django

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I am trying to add recaptcha to my review form. I created an account and have the secret/public keys corrrect. The problem i have having is that when i go to submit the form, my views.py gets a response of None and an invalid-input-response.

because of this, my review does not get created weather i click 'i am not a robot' or not.

this is the logic to validate the recaptcha in views

```
def create_review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
            'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }

        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
        req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        print(values)
        print(result)
        if result['success']:
            print(result['success'])
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            rating = request.POST.get('rating')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            
            review = Testimonial(name=name, rating=rating, message=message)
            review.save()
```

These are the variables that are printed

```
{'secret': 'private_key', 'response': None}
{'success': False, 'error-codes': ['invalid-input-response']}
```

this is the html in my html form

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public_site_key"></div>`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like no such key as  'g-recaptcha-response'  exists in the dict.  recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')

Comment: try using request.POST['g-recaptcha-response'] and see the error. You should have 'g-recaptcha-response'  as name= of capcha field in the templates.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried that but i get the error                                            
 django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'g-recaptcha-response                       so it seems that the form does not recognize the captcha widget

Comment: I can't say what might be causing this error but plz don't use dict's .get method unnecessarily. Use  d["somekey"] notation to catch the errors. Also <div name="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public_site_key"></div>, I hope you ve done this